# How to get path of an element in lxml?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm searching in a HTML document using XPath from lxml in python. How can I get the path to a certain element? Here's the example from ruby nokogiri:

```
page.xpath('//text()').each do |textnode|
    path = textnode.path
    puts path
end
```

print for example '**/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/p/text()[1]**' and this is the string I want to get in python.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use [`getpath`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getpath) from ElementTree objects.

```py
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring('''
    <foo><bar>Data</bar><bar><baz>data</baz>
    <baz>data</baz></bar></foo>
    ''')

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
for e in root.iter():
    print(tree.getpath(e))
```

Prints

```
/foo
/foo/bar[1]
/foo/bar[2]
/foo/bar[2]/baz[1]
/foo/bar[2]/baz[2]
```

Comment: I think it should be `for e in tree.iter():`, i.e. **tree**.iter.

Comment: @Jabba And why do you think that? Have you tried the code I provided the way it is? It seems to work, no? Do you have a **reason** to think otherwise?

Comment: It might have not existed when you wrote this originally and not that it actually matters, but you can also do `tree = root.getroottree()` to get an ElementTree object.

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, when I use ```https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/``` to pull a webpage, I do the following: ```webpage = session.get('URL HERE')``` then ```root = etree.HTML(webpage.text)``` then ```tree = etree.ElementTree(root)``` and then simply the for loop as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 20):

See the [Xpath and XSLT with lxml from the lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) This gives the path of the element containg the text

An example would be

```
import cStringIO
from lxml import etree

f = cStringIO.StringIO('<foo><bar><x1>hello</x1><x1>world</x1></bar></foo>')
tree = lxml.etree.parse(f)
find_text = etree.XPath("//text()")

# and print out the required data
print [tree.getpath( text.getparent()) for text in find_text(tree)]

# answer I get is 
>>> ['/foo/bar/x1[1]', '/foo/bar/x1[2]']
```

Answer (score 14):

If all you have in your section of code is the element and you want the element's xpath do then `element.getroottree().getpath(element)` will do the job.

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''
<test>
    <a/>
    <b>
       <i/>
       <ii/>
    </b>
</test>
'''
tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

for element in tree.iter():
    print element.getroottree().getpath(element)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
root = etree.parse(open('tmp.txt'))

for e in root.iter():
    print root.getpath(e)
```