# Store and load XML node in Python

Tags: python, xml

I would like to be able to store the path to the current XML node I'm visiting in a database so to load it later. E.g.

```
<somenode>
    <child>This is something I'm interested in storing in a database...</child>
    <child>...and this is not :(</child>
</somenode>
```

So, what I want to do, is to store some kind of path to the node I'm interested in, so to be able to quickly navigate to such node when I need it.

Comment: There are quite a number of XML parsers in Python, most of which are listed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python?rq=1). Have you tried any of those yet?

Comment: I did, what I'm looking for(and I wonder if there is) is some kind of node "path" so that i can save this path at any point and simply use it later in order to quickly load the node it refers to.

Comment: See the top answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577293/how-to-get-path-of-an-element-in-lxml). This will provide you a specific path in the form `'/somenode/child[1]'` for example.