# Python lxml getpath error

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to get a full list of xpaths from a device config in xml.

When I run it though I get:

```
 AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getpath'
```

Code is just a few lines

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import os
from lxml import etree

file1 = 'C:\Users\test1\Desktop\test.xml'
file1_path = file1.replace('\\','/')


e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(file1_path).getroot()

for entry in e.iter():
    print e.getpath(entry)
```

anyone come across this before ?

Thanks

Richie

Comment: I'm trying to get it to dump out the full XPath of a files elements . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577293/how-to-get-path-of-an-element-in-lxml Seems to say it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it incorrectly, don't call getroot just parse and iter using ***lxml***.etree:

```
import lxml.etree as et

file1 = 'C:/Users/test1/Desktop/test.xml'

root = et.parse(file1)
for e in root.iter():
    print root.getpath(e)
```

If you are dealing with namespaces you may find `getelementpath` usefule:

```
 root.getelementpath(e)
```

Comment: Thanks man looks better. Doesn't show the values just the paths so ill go figure out how to do that.