# Not able to get the Xpath from an already selected element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am scrolling on a WebPage until i manage to find a specific text.
When i find the text I want to get the Xpath of the element. I managed to implement the finding part but i dont know how to get the Xpath of selected element.

My code:

```
find_elem = None   #variable used as a flag

while not find_elem:
   time.sleep(2)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)  #used for scrolling

   time.sleep(2)
   try:
        find_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'text_i_am_looking_for')]")))
        time.sleep(2)
        find_elem.click()
        
        print(find_elem.getpath())  
   except:
        pass
```

**My expected output:**  Xpath of find_elem
**Actual output:** 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getpath'

Some more context:
What i want to acomplish in the end is to read and write value 5 of parameter named text_i_am_looking_for (check picture below). So I want to first find the parameter by name and somehow navigate to the parameter value from there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN8Vk.png

Comment: Seems `getpath()` is a method of the [root element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37769448/2834978).

Comment: the xpath is matched here:  
find_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'text_i_am_looking_for')]")))
But i dont know a way to retrive it. I also used debug in py charm and looked at the information encapsulated in WebElement object but not managed to find the current xpath address