# Print actual XPath using Python 2.7 ElementTree Library

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath

I have the following python code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
from optparse import OptionParser
import ConfigParser
import fileinput, sys
import os


config_file = 'ClientConfig.xml'
tree = et.parse(config_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root.findall("/client/config/TEST_CLIENT"):
    for elem in element.iter(tag='Item'):
        print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

Is there a way for me to print the xpath directly for each element as opposed to rebuilding it using the elem.tag and elem.attrib options? That is, I want to be able to print each elements full xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use [`lxml.etree` and `getpath()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577293/how-to-get-path-of-an-element-in-lxml) for it:

```
for element in root.findall("/client/config/TEST_CLIENT"):
    for elem in element.iter(tag='Item'):
        print(tree.getpath(elem))
```

Comment: This ended up being the solution. I was avoiding lxml but its far superior to ElementTree